# Understanding the tangle index in sonarqube

Tags: java, sonarqube, sonar-runner

I have my project anaylzed through sonar qube and the tangle index has one higer number then the actual number of cyclic dependencies listed. Is it displaying a wrong number or is it a correct number and why ?  In the below project the number of cyclic dependencies are listed as 3 but it displays only two classes and it is same with almost all my other projects(one higher number then actual depenedecies). 
Can any one explain me why it is adding one number to the actual dependencies ?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are experiencing is a bug from the SonarQube Java plugin, see [SONARJAVA-1184](http://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARJAVA-1184).

As you can read on the ticket, this bug won't be fixed because the existing design-related features will be dropped in SonarQube 5.2. You can read more about the reasons why on the following ticket: [SONAR-6553](http://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONAR-6553).